# How to prevent text selection while using VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

If I have a component that renders some text and make an initial click somewhere on the text (for example at the beginning) and then the second time a shift-click on another part of the text (for example at the end) the text between those 2 click positions is selected.

How can I prevent this from happening using a pure VueJS solution if possible?

Answer (score 4):

It's not Vue related, just use a CSS rule:

```
user-select:none;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: That seems to work even if not pure VueJS solution.

Comment: There is no pure Vue solution because this isn't a problem Vue is meant to solve. Don't overthink the problem. standard CSS, JS and HTML are all meant to be used _with_ Vue, not be _replaced_ by Vue.